# Damaged paint on fork dropouts (magnesium) – is it dangerous?

Tags: fork, paint

I've noticed that paint on my Reba fork peels off near quick release dropouts. The lowers are made of magnesium according to RS website. Should I regard it as a cosmetic issue only, or is it in any way dangerous? There are no other damages.

[image]

How can I prevent it from peeling off further?

Note: edited to include information about material.

Comment: What are the forks made of (test with a magnet if you have no other way of knowing whether they're steel or aluminium)?

Comment: @ChrisH, Reba lowers are made of magnesium according to RS website.

Comment: That's highly relevant; it's an unusal material.  I suggest you edit it into your quesion (even the title) .

Comment: I'd pick off that loose bit, lightly sand and lap the edges, and paint on some model paint acrylic-enamel, or maybe colour-matching nail polish.  Then I'd leave it to set for a time and do a second, maybe even a third coat.  I wouldn't clearcoat a patch.   There's no functional reason to do this, its my own piece of mind.  The magnesium won't rust.

Answer (score 5):

It probably won't peel further (you can apply whatever paint you want around the edges if you want), but the issue is just cosmetic.

My suggestion is just to ignore it and move on with life.

Answer (score 0):

Completely cosmetic. The paint is bound to wear in this area when the QR skewer is tightened, applying pressure by the axle against the dropout's surface. There's no need to worry about preventing further wear as you now have metal on metal contact between the dropout and the axle. Just make sure the QR is tight, as a loose skewer *can* cause damage to either or both components due to slippage. That doesn't appear to be the case here.